# Who is showing up on the direct share contact list

Tags: share-menu

hello I have a quick question 
Is it possible a contact that you haven't used in a few months to show up in the direct share quick contacts? Or the contacts that show up tehrr are always Recently used or most Frequently used contacts?
Thanks[image]